# Single Row Table in SQL : Is this a good implementation?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. I read a bit about how creating a single row table is not really a good practice, but I can't help but find it useful in my case. I am making a web app which balances the workload of employees in the organization. So apart from keeping track of how much work is assigned to every employee and how much work does each task (2 main task types) require, I also need to track the overall workload.

So I plan to make a single row table for total workload, with three columns. One for each of the two task types, summed together. And the third for the sum of those 2 totals. I plan to use triggers to update the table in case of addition of a new task or change in its requirements so that it reflects on the total.

Please let me know if I am heading in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on which product you're using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc), there may be features built into the product that will save you some work. In SQL Server you may be able to build an indexed view. In Oracle, a materialized view. In these cases, the product does the maintenance automatically for you.

Comment: Okay, I am using MYSQL. I planned to use triggers and procedures, but from what you are saying, there's a better way to do it I assume? Please throw some more light on the same, @Damien_The_Unbeliever . Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work but it is not extensible, in the sense if tomorrow you need to add a 3rd main task then you will need to alter the table and add another column (not so preferred ). So may be you can just have the table with two columns for now with task type and load and you can always calculate the sum with sql query.

Comment: Thanks. That's a handy tip. :)